# Bubble in OSMDROID

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

In the main screen of OSMDROID's webpage can be saw the use of bubble of information but I don't know how implement this funcionality. I searched how do it in the official documentation, internet and stackoverflow but I don't find anything.

Does this functionality available in the library or just is part of OSMViewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the viewer program is on Google Code so you can see how they've done everything:
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FOpenStreetMapViewer

I think that what you're looking for is a ItemizedOverlayWithFocus, used here:
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithMinimapItemizedoverlayWithFocus.java

Comment: @Kieran please have alook at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799221/nullpointerexception-android-java-using-osmdroid

Answer (score 3):

Check out this thread, Post #5:

https://groups.google.com/group/osmdroid/browse_frm/thread/262444b24373385b?hl=en#

With this new library you can have much better 'infowindows' than the rather limited ItemizedOverlayWithFocus:

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/

I haven't tested it myself yet but it looks good.

Comment: @Martin Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799221/nullpointerexception-android-java-using-osmdroid